# Write to another already running process stdin from Node.js without starting from inside

Tags: node.js, process, stdout, stdin

I have a program that isn't started from inside Node.js, so I cannot use `spawn`'d stdin to write to. I have the PID of the process that is listening for stdin input, how can I write to it using my node code?

I always see code examples using `child_process` module, and my use case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you should be able to write to `'/proc/' + pid + '/fd/0'`. However this isn't portable.

Comment: hmm I see, so to retain cross-plataform support I'd need to use TCP... I really didn't want to though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the process id then one can use [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) or one of its variants: [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) or [ltrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ltrace) to control, manipulate, and view process information and communication.